# Floating neutral in TN-S or TN-C-S earthing system

Tags: grounding, floating

Since neutral is bonded to ground at building distribution point in a TN-S or TN-C-S earthing system, could floating neutral happen under the following conditions:

1. Loss of N and/or PE at transformer
2. Loss of N and/or PE at building distribution point
3. Loss of N and/or PE at transformer and building distribution point

I'm trying to understand how to prevent floating neutral in a 3-phase power supply and thus avoid damage to low voltage equipments connected to a single phase.

Comment: Is this in the UK? and you are referring to the UK wiring regs for TN-S etc

Comment: @SolarMike Yes, UK wiring regulations for TN-S and TN-C-S earthing systems.

Comment: Add that info to the question, add the UK tag.

Answer (score 1):

Speaking about TN-C-S, the N an PE are the same wire on building input-PEN, floating N also means floating PE:

The PEN wire has to be connected to the building ground and/or earthing rods/strips buried in place.

In such way all PEN conductors make a grounding mesh connection, if one fails the other takes over. The most important is the one in place: if the incoming PEN is broken, then you still have a ground connection through your's ground, otherwise all the metallic parts would get on live potential.

For TN-S the PE and N are separated, a floating N isn't an issue.

Comment: The (very) difficult bit is to achieve a ground resistance low enough to achieve anything useful in the event of a lost PEN connection.  Most UK installations don't even try.

Comment: @SimonB Why not? I guess UK is not on sand soil. The problem would be achieving low resistance in Saudi Arabia or Kalahari, Sahara desert, but not in UK. For sure the buildings in UK have a grounding which have very low resistance.

Comment: A 3 phase supply in the UK is usually at least 100A, 230/400V.  A simple earth rod may give you a few hundred ohms resistance.  But suppose you bury something more substantial and achieve 10 ohms.  A broken PEN won't give a fault current through the earth more than about 230/10 = 23A.  That's nowhere near enough to blow the supply fuse.  Meanwhile, that earth mat will still be sitting somewhere close to the supply voltage, and getting rather warm.  There was a proposal to add a requirement for earth rods on TN-C-S supplies to the IEE Wiring Regulations recently.  It was abandoned.

Comment: If the building is grounded and all metallic parts including piping,..etc then let's suppose the PEN is broken. All the building, including yourself will rise at the ground potential, so there is no difference of potential while touching the metal case. If the grounding impedance with all buried rods and foundations can't be smaller than X ohms, then even your body can't in any circumstance be better grounded to produce a potential difference.

Comment: So to conclude in TNS system floating neutral isn't an issue but it is in TN-C-S right? I'm afraid I'm dealing with the latter most of the time.

Comment: @Joseph It's almost both the same, TN-S floating PE, TN-C-S floating PEN. In any case you need the PE/PEN to be connected to building ground, earthing rods, pipes,..as per regulations.

Comment: In a star connected 3 phase system with a broken neutral, is there a proper method to measure which return path a 'neutral bonded to earth' building circuit would take? I think we can all agree that current flowing to earth is a good thing as it would trip an RCCB. But the problem is when the current "chooses" to take the return path via the other phase to which a low resistance load is connected. At least a lower resistance than the ground. According to @SimonB ground R could be in the 10s to 100s of ohms. Where as say my laptop rated at 19.5V/9.23A offers up only 2.1 Ω resistance 1/2

Comment: which I assume would be the return path the current "chooses" while destroying my laptop? 2/2

Comment: @Joseph The RCD won't trip, because it measures the sum of all currents, I1+I2+I3+In=0, so if the device insulation is not damaged, then you won't get any difference. I can confirm you (my experience) that in case of loss of neutral, your laptop charger will blow, as you already found out.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič A 3P+N RCD will trip if the current flows to ground but yeah, not if it flows through the other phase. Thanks to that equation, I just had an idea! How about connecting a single phase double pole (L-N) RCD to each of the 3 lines? That should take care of floating neutral without this (https://i.imgur.com/CgdIIL5.png) mess of a wiring diagram with voltage protection relays and contactors  right?

Comment: Its probably not a good idea to use RCD for overvoltage protection due to floating neutral as EN 50550 standard for power frequency overvoltage protection (permanent overvoltage protection) device says: "Prohibition on using earth leakage or current differential as operating principles.". My solution was to use voltage protection relays and contactors (or shunt trip) for each phase. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/175959/will-a-rcbo-4p-trip-in-case-of-neutral-fault-failure-interrupt-float/447814#447814